# Is it possible to display different data in JTable fields using one object?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Being that what gets displayed in the JTable is the stored object's `toString`, is it somehow possible to display other information?

For example, if I have a simple user object like this:

### User

```
class User {
  private String firstname; 
  private String lastname;
  ... 
}
```

Can I display the `first` and `last` name properties in their own column in a JTable?

Like this:

[image]

Currently, I'm storing the string properties of the `User` object in the `JTable` rather than the `User` object itself.

### e.g.

```
// where first/lastname are the strings retrieved 
// via getFirstname() and getLastname() on the User object. 
model.addRow(new Object[] {first, last });
```

However, the problem with this is all the book keeping involved anytime I need to retrieve and build the Object that the user clicks on in the JTable. Is it possible to store the User object in the JTable, but have it display different properties depending on the column it's in?

Comment: is the stored object's toString, - please why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Just define a different [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) to each column:

```
User user = new User("Zack", "Yoshyaro");

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"First", "Last"}, 0);
model.addRow(new Object[]{user, user});  // note user must be added for each column, but it's the same object
JTable table = new JTable(model);

TableColumn firstName = table.getColumn("First");
firstName.setCellRenderer(...); // a cell renderer that shows user.getFirstName();

TableColumn lastName = table.getColumn("Last");
lastName.setCellRenderer(...); // a cell renderer that shows user.getLastName();
```

See [Using custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) section in [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial.